# Module to search node titles only

Tags: 7, search

Is there a module that allows me to restrict searches to node titles, rather than any node content? 
Preferably the user would choose between titles only or everything.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Views Search](http://drupal.org/project/views_search) and build a views with only the title of nodes as an exposed filter, then this module convert your exposed filter in a search option.